# Xamarin forms ViewCell in listview - sending to the variable

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, contextmenu, menuitem

How can I send a data which is saved in a class:

```
public class Person

{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public string UserType { get; set; }


}
```

to the variable?

I'm saving data (in another class) like this:

```
 var persons = new List<Person>();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {

            // get the results of each column
            int id = (int)dr1["ID_Instructor"];
            string firstname = (string)dr1["f_name"];
            string lastname = (string)dr1["l_name"];
            string school = (string)dr1["d_school"];
            string category = (string)dr1["category"];

            var person = new Person
            {
                Id = id,
                Fullname = firstname + " " + lastname,
                Details = school + " " + category
            };

            persons.Add(person);
        }
```

and in the same class I want to send it to the variable from menuItem by the BindingContext. I just need to print all of this data (from one person from list)

```
private void MenuItem_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;

        if (menuItem != null)

            var name = menuItem.BindingContex;
```

Comment: You need to share more code with us, for example we need to see your XAML code for your view.

Comment: I solved my problem by myself.

My function was wrong. It was all about sending a correct parameter:

`private void MenuItem_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;

            if (menuItem != null)
            {
                var name = menuItem.BindingContext as Person;

                var name2 = name.Id;


                 Navigation.PushAsync(new PersonPage(name2));
            }
        }
`

Comment: Nice to hear that!